Is it possible to adapt Nigel’s Smart algorithm for establishing an isomorphism when the curve is only partially anomalous?
An anomalous elliptic curve is a curve for which $\#E(\mathbf{F}_q ) = q$.
But in my case, the curve has order $j×q$ and the underlying field has order $i×q$. In the situation I’m thinking about, I do have 2 points such as both $G∈q$ and $P∈q$ subgroup and where $P=s×G$.
So since the scalar $s$ lies in a common part of the additive group from both the curve along it’s underlying base field, is it possible to transfer the discrete logarithm to the underlying finite field ?
Or does anomalous curves requires the whole embedding field’s order to match the one of the curve even if the discrete logarithm solution lies into a common smaller group?
If yes, how to adapt the Nigel’s smart algorithm used for solving the discrete logarithm inside anomalous curves? The aim is to etablish an isomorphism between the common subgroup generated by E and $_$
Update
Since this was asked, let’s take an example to test. Let’s have the following curve
p = 0x2523648240000001BA344D80000000086121000000000013A700000000000013
K = GF(p)
a = K(0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000)
b = K(0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000002)
E = EllipticCurve(K, (a, b))
G = E(0x2523648240000001BA344D80000000086121000000000013A700000000000012, 0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001)   
E.set_order(0x2523648240000001BA344D8000000007FF9F800000000010A10000000000000D * 0x01)
E_semi_anomalous = E.base_extend(GF(p^12))

and determine the discrete logarithm between those 2 points
pk=E_semi_anomalous.random_point()*ZZ(E_semi_anomalous.order()//E.order())
sk=E_semi_anomalous.random_point()*ZZ(E_semi_anomalous.order()//E.order())

Given the prime E.order() exist in the GF(p**12) base field and also the discrete logarithm lies in the E.order() subgroup.

Can I check what you mean when you say that the underlying field has order $i\times q$. Finite fields all have $p^n$ elements for some prime $p$ and natural number $n$. Do you mean that $i=p^a$ and $q=p^b$ for some prime $p$?

@DanielS I’m meaning $p−1$ has $i×q$ as prime factors. That is, factorization of $p−1$ is $i×q$.

Its not possible. Why? Because you are trying to find more of a "pseudo"-isomorphism. It doesn't work that way. See the point addition operation as a graph and finite field as another graph. The number of vertices aren't same. So no you can't translate a curve, just because it shares a prime factor. However, to test it I would need some concrete examples.

@madhurkant example added.

@user2284570 I do not know to use sage math. Can you clarify if the order of subgroup generated is prime or not?

@madhurkant you can read the code if you can t write it. The order of the subgroup generated is $0x2523648240000001BA344D8000000007FF9F800000000010A10000000000000D$. So it s prime.

It may exist, with a weak yes. You can try running for $C : y^2 = x^3 + 11$ over $\mathbb{F}_{109}$ the order of subgroup generated by, $G=(1, 11)$will be $129$.

@madhurkant Why F109? what s the link berween the order I m looking at in the example and what you talk about? Or what do you mean by weak key? It seems to me you are talking about a non Weistrass curve.

@madhurkant Ok the right word is to establish an isomorphism between the common subgroup.

@user2284570 Not weak key but a weak yes. Maybe I am failing to understand what you mean by $P \in q$ and $Q \in q$. I am not optimistic for a solution because it breaks ECDLP and its consequences will be far reaching. ECDSA is around for quite a time, had such a vulnerability exist it would have been exploited and known. Nevertheless, new vulnerability are always being discovered.

@madhurkant ECDSA doesn t use curves liekely insecure that share subgroups/suborder between the curve s order and the finite field s order. What I m meaning about $P$ and $Q$ is they are in the same subgroup which is common to the underlying field.

I have been thinking about it since a long time, even before you posted this, for now I can only tell you it works. However significant changes might be required to my approach. Currently not publishing due to three reasons: A. No general proof but a method B. If applied on a more general scale, it can potentially break some of the secure curves. (Not sure about it) C. Trying to figure out another method so that it doesn't reveal much. So yes bounty period will expire but diligence is necessary.

@madhurkant It seems there s misconceptions because secure curves definitely don t have such weaknesses like this. Maybe we can talk about it privately? I m an experienced bounty hunter if you check my Stack Exchange profile.

What you are noticing here is that the elliptic curve in question has a relatively small embedding degree, which is indeed not a common property for random elliptic curves, and can lead to a vulnerability (the MOV attack, completely unrelated to the anomalous curve attack) if parameters are not chosen carefully. But people do generate curves with small embedding degrees very deliberately for a good reason: because they support pairings (they are pairing-friendly curves). And they choose parameters in such a way that the MOV attack is not a significant threat.
In the case of the curve you consider, the parameters are a bit old, so the conjectured security nowadays is a bit worse than when the curve was initially proposed, due to TNFS style attacks in $\mathbb{F}_{p^{12}}$; it should still be around 100 bits though, so you are unlikely to break it.

Wrong. There s an embedding degree when the curve is prime. The mov attack uses pairings to transfer the ECDLP from the prime curve to the extension field of the curve. But here, the discrete logarithm to solve is directly on the curve s extension field. Or rephrased, the embedding degree is 1 instead of 12 which seems maybe to highlight possible additive ismorphism.

You seem to be confused. You may be failing to realize that for a curve $E/\mathbb{F}_p$, the order of $E(\mathbb{F}p)$ always divides that of $E(\mathbb{F}{p^d})$ for any $d\geq 1$ (for the simple reason that the $\mathbb{F}_p$-points are in particular points over the extension.

If I wanted to solve a discrete logarithm on E instead of E_semi_anomalous, I would need pairing with the extension field of E such as the underlying $F_p^n$ field contains the order of E which is E_semi_anomalous. But in that case, the discrete logarithm to solve is directly on E_semi_anomalous.

It is in the subgroup of order E.order() of E_semi_anomalous, which is exactly the set of $\mathbb{F}_p$-points, so you're really solving a discrete log on $E$. That being said, curves of embedding degree 1 do exist (these are curves of trace 2), and the relevant attack is still MOV (or FR-reduction, but that's fundamentally the same attack). Smart's attack targerts curves of trace 1, which are a totally different beast. I resisted the urge of starting this comment by Wrong in bold letters, by the way.

Yes but E.order() doesn t divide 0x2523648240000001BA344D80000000086121000000000013A700000000000013 at all. I meaning the modulus of E. Whereas this is partly the case with E_semi_anomalous.

No, $p$ doesn't divide the order of $E(\mathbb{F}{p^{12}})$. The order of $E(\mathbb{F}{p^{12}})$ can be computed in Sage as R.<t> = PowerSeriesRing(QQ); E.zeta_series(12,t).log()[12]*12, and you can check that it is not divisible by $p$. The smallest degree of an extension on which $E$ has a point of order $p$ is the multiplicative order mod $p$ of the Frobenius trace, namely 933228262834212904718933563457318550549399284524392769385206412559597436929.

No what I m meaning is the order of the points divides   $0x2523648240000001BA344D80000000086121000000000013A700000000000013^{12}$

If there is a point other than the identity with order dividing $p^{12}$, then there is a point of exact order $p$, obviously, and as I have noted above, this is not the case. Clearly, you seem to have made an error in some computation somewhere.

Smart attack can’t work.
To being with you cannot say a curve is anomalous while it’s order being different from the finite field itself. Taking your example the sagemath E.order() returns 0x2523648240000001ba344d8000000007ff9f800000000010a10000000000000.
So for your case $\#E(F_p) \neq p$ but say $\#E(F_p) = n$.
No smart attack is strictly for anomalous curve. But what you present further is significant.
A potential to apply Smart?
Then you calculate the prime factors of these:
$p - 1 = 2 \times 3^2 \times 7 \times 641 \times 71693 \times {1033337} \times {15698303} \times {65982793} \times {5994341377} \times {22009001472962227} \times {6848045079628454069}$
$n - 1 = 2^2 × 3 × 7 × 641 × {16843} × {140977} × {15698303} × {65982793} × {101148471075752777} × {1254043595354617963043866617659}$
and argues whether due to these similar prime factors, resulting in subgroups, you can use Smart’s attack. The observation is interesting. Can it work? No but first let’s tweak it and then test it.
You have gone too far in your example. Let’s make it simple. Consider $E: y^2 = x^3 + 4$ over $\mathbb{F}_{1009}$ the $\#E(\mathbb{F}_{1009}) = 1029$, a non-prime, but order of subgroup generated by $G = (25, 764)$ will be $7$
$1008 = 2^4 \times 3^2 \times 7$ and
$7 = 7$
The set of points will be
$[(25,764),(352, 930), (902, 636), (902, 373), (352,79), (25, 245), (\infty, \infty)]$
Let $G = (25, 764)$ and $P = (902, 636)$ we need to find $k = 3$ such that $P=kG$.
Let us first lift these to $\mathbb{Q}_{p}$ fixing $x-$ coordinate we get these as $G_q = (25, 764 + 831 \times 1009)$ and $P_q = (902, 636 + 581 \times 1009)$
Additionally we have to modify smart’s method a little instead of calculating $pP_p$ and $pG_p$ we calculate $7P_q$ and $7G_q$ in $E(Q_{p})$. Because we are no longer worried about whole $p$ but only a subgroup whose order is $7$.
$7P_q = (87 \times 1009^{-2}, 309 \times 1009^{-3})$
$7G_q = (796 \times 1009^{-2}, 343 \times 1009^{-3})$
Now since we have all required info: we can calculate
$\phi(7P_q) \equiv - \frac{87 \times 1009^{-2}}{309 \times 1009^{-3}} \equiv 803 \times 1009 (\mod {1009^2})$
$\phi(7G_q) \equiv - \frac{796 \times 1009^{-2}}{343 \times 1009^{-3}} \equiv 486 \times 1009 (\mod{1009^2})$
we can calculate k as follows:
$k \equiv \frac{\phi(G_p)}{\phi(P_q)}$
Finally we shall reduce this problem to $\#E(\mathbb{F}_1009)$ taking modulo $7$
$k \equiv \frac{\phi(G_q)}{\phi(P_q)} \mod{7}$
Substituting values:
$ k \equiv 3 \mod{7}$
We can also reduce it modulo order of the curve $1029$ in which case
$k \equiv 605 \mod{1029}$
We can verify that both k are true.
Above works because even when you have a subgroup, of prime order $i$, we know for any point, say $r(x,y)$ in that subgroup $ i \times r = I = (\infty, \infty)$. This allow us to map elements the details can be seen in Section 6.1 here just replace $p$ with $i$ and remember example 6.2 has miscalculation.
Can we use Smart’s attack on the example in question?
Probably No. Why? Because the order of group is prime. When order of a curve over a field is prime it means that there are those numbers of points and each point has the prime order. You cannot have “Subgroups” in such a case.
This is more of mathematical. Fundamental theorem of cyclic groups states For any cyclic group of order $n$ every subgroup’s order is a divisor of $n$, and there is exact one subgroup for each divisor of $n$. Hence for curves of prime order over a field there is only one and one subgroup.
Hence curves having prime order are secure.
But wait… why the word ‘probably’? That’s where we need to expand our thinking. See if there is something more fundamental and profound in your example or prime order curves. Can you see it? That’s why I commented “If applied on a more general scale, it can potentially break some of the secure curves. (Not sure about it)“ 

You did not understood the question. The whole order of the curve in the example is not prime. Yes it s not fully anomalous, but the 2 orders have a common subgroup/factor. I also read about a similar thing on https://safecurves.cr.yp.to/twist.html where addative transfers might be possible.

@user2284570 1. If you are saying for my example then yes its not prime. For your exapmple Sage says otherwise E.order().is_prime() yields True. 2. On safecurve page, assuming you are talking about small subgroup attack,. To conduct such an attack the smaller subgroup should exist. The only "small" subgroup on prime order curve is ${e}$ the trivial subgroup and you can't do anything with it.

You read the code incorrectly E is only used to build E_semi_anomalous. The problem is on E_semi_anomalous. Also the safecurve page talks about curve twists where addtive transfer is possible on prime curves examples.

I was hoping that a "proper cryptographer" would have taken a stab at this, but I hashed something out on a piece of paper because I wasn't sure what you were asking.  I didn't even know of the Smart's algorithm you mentioned, so I read the paper... this is what I got, but be mindful of this disclaimer.
$P=s×G$ makes this work out because it combines a curve that is not fully anomalous, but retains specific structural properties that could make adaptations of Smart’s algorithm feasible.
Smart's original algorithm exploits $\#E(\mathbf{F}_q ) = q$. , effectively making the curve behave like an additive group over $\mathbf{F}_q$​.  This is great because that's what basically all discrete logarithm structures are, so this is where you start.
The subgroup of order $q$ also provides opportunities here. You can treat the $q$-subgroup as the effective group for discrete logarithm, because it can be anything, such as finite field.   This means that you'll need a $G$ that generates a subgroup that satisfies all operations modulo $q$.
There are a lot of things that I believe have the potential to go wrong here still, but I could easy make it workout with a small $q$.

this isn’t a full answer. You can test your ideas here https://github.com/jvdsn/crypto-attacks/blob/master/attacks/ecc/smart_attack.py https://github.com/jvdsn/crypto-attacks/issues/22 using https://neuromancer.sk/std/bn/bn254 as an example. The point of my question is having a possible subset of an additive group between the curve and $F_q$

@user2284570 I see what you're going for there now.  I've updated the question to better point that out.

More exactly, my aim is to make the subgroup/suborder to behave like an additive group since everything happens in that group.

Example added to the question.

With math evrything is possible.
You can resolve ecdlp in small partially anomalous with lift point Call smart attack.

I was talking about Nigel’s Smart algorithm.

Yes its possible because Anomalous curve Can be couple with other curve.

As far I know it’s supersingular curves that can pair with an other curve. But then the discrete logarithm is multiplicative so solved in subexponenential time instead of polynomial time.

Nope any  curve or prime curve Can be pairing with other change paramater a and b in équation y^2=x^3+ax+b to obtain the Anomalous and other curve in one

You don t solve multiplicarive discrete logarithm in a 3000 bits field (my case). But additive discrete logarithm is a simple inversion (I m talking about finite fields without curves). So I need the Nigel smart algorithm. Not pairings.

You need pairing in your case if you want solve non Anomalous curve with Nigel smart. For non curve i don t know.

The suborder/subgroup of the discrete logarithm exists in the finite field.
